# HAVING all the elements of a purchase

Tags: mysql, sql, select, having

I'm having trouble with a `SELECT`. I'm working in MySQL.

I want to get the "consumidor" email that bought products ("Produto") that includes every "Elemento".

I did this:

```
SELECT C.email
FROM Consumidor C, composto composto, compra compra
WHERE C.numero = compra.consumidor

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT composto.elemento) = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                             FROM Elemento E)
```

But It didn't work. I got only one result and I know that there's more. I know that there's missing stuff between `WHERE` and `HAVING`.

**TABLES**

```
Create table  Consumidor  (
    numero  int(9),
    email   varchar(30) not null,
    sexo    char(1) not null,
    nascimento  date    not null,
    constraint Consumidor_sexo_RI001     check (sexo in ('F','M')),
    constraint Consumidor_unique_RI002  unique(email),
    constraint pk_Consumidor     primary key (numero)
);
Create table  Elemento  (
    codigo  char(3),
    nome    varchar(25) not null,
    pegadaEcologica int(2) not null,
    saude   int(2) not null,
    constraint pk_Elemento   primary key (codigo)
);
Create table  Produto  (
    codigo  int(6),
    marca   int(7),
    nome    varchar(50) not null,
    tipo    char(10),
    comercioJusto   char(1),
    constraint Produto_tipo_RI004   check (tipo in ('alimentac','lar','jardim','automov','viagem','electrodom')),
    constraint Produto_comercioJusto_RI005   check (comercioJusto in ('A','B','C','D')),
    constraint fk_Produto_marca  foreign key (marca) references Marca(numero) on delete cascade,
    constraint pk_Produto    primary key (codigo,marca)
);
Create table  compra  (
    produto int(6),
    prodMarca   int(7),
    consumidor  int(9),
    quantidade  decimal(10,3)   not null,
    constraint compra_quantidade_RI006  check (quantidade>0),
    constraint fk_compra_produto     foreign key (produto,prodMarca) references Produto(codigo,marca) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_compra_consumidor  foreign key (consumidor) references Consumidor(numero) on delete cascade,
    constraint pk_compra     primary key (produto,prodMarca,consumidor)
);
Create table  composto  (
    produto int(6),
    prodMarca   int(7),
    elemento    char(3),
    percentagem decimal(4,1)    not null,
    constraint composto_percentagem_RI007   check (percentagem>0 and percentagem<=100),
    constraint fk_composto_produto   foreign key (produto,prodMarca) references Produto(codigo,marca) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_composto_elemento  foreign key (elemento) references Elemento(codigo) on delete cascade,
    constraint pk_composto   primary key (produto,prodMarca,elemento)
);
```

Comment: Essentially this feels like a duplicate of your previous questions on this topic.

Comment: Learn SQL syntax.  `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`.  HAVING without GROUP BY of course will blow up your query.  Google SQL syntax.

Comment: @Strawberry, it's not, but all my question are for the same project, so they sound alike ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Having

Your use of the [`HAVING`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) functionality is incorrect. What you're saying as that the number of your `elemento` (Product Details) should equal the count of your `Composto` (Products to Product Details table).

The reason why you're only getting 1 row, is that you're joining the [`Count`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx), or number of rows, from your Product Details table to the count of the items you've retrieved.

Try this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Elemento E`

and you will see that there's only 1 single sum which gets returned (the number of actual Product Details you have).

Now try:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT composto.elemento) FROM composto`

and you will see that the numbers match.

All you're doing is counting the number of items. That's clearly not what you're looking for as this is not the correct way to refine your results.

### Relational joins

Additionally, you're not joining your tables correctly. MySQL is a '[relational database](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)' which means that you need to specifically define the 'relationships' between your objects (tables).

To begin with, you need to update your query to correct your joins:

```
 SELECT Customer.email, ProductDetails.nome
 FROM Consumidor Customer

    -- Joins the Consumidor (consumer) table to the Compra (sales) table
    INNER JOIN compra Sales
        ON Customer.numero = Sales.consumidor

    -- Joins the sales to the Produto (products) table
    INNER JOIN Producto Product
        ON Sales.produto = Product.codigo

    -- Joins the composto (Composite Key) table to the elemento (Product Details) table
    INNER JOIN composto
        ON composto.produto = Product.codigo

    -- Now get the Product details
    INNER JOIN elemento ProductDetails
        ON composto.elemento = ProductDetails.codigo
```

Now, your joins should work properly, you'll get the Person (Customer), the products they bought (compra) and the details about the products.

## Get the results

I'm assuming what you want is a subset of the `Produto` (Products). If that's correct, then what you need to do is to define your [predicates](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlpredicates.php) correctly, using your ['WHERE'](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) clause:

```
SELECT Customer.email, ProductDetails.nome
FROM Consumidor Customer

    -- Joins the Consumidor (consumer) table to the Compra (sales) table
    INNER JOIN compra Sales
        ON Customer.numero = Sales.consumidor

    -- Joins the sales to the Produto (products) table
    INNER JOIN Producto Product
        ON Sales.produto = Product.codigo

    -- Joins the composto (Composite Key) table to the elemento (Product Details) table
    INNER JOIN composto
        ON composto.produto = Product.codigo

    -- Now get the Product details
    INNER JOIN elemento ProductDetails
        ON composto.elemento = ProductDetails.codigo
-- You can search for whatever matches your criteria here    
WHERE Customer.nome = 'Möoz' -- Finds all products that user 'Möoz' has bought
```

You can also add or remove predicates in your 'WHERE' clause to refine your search:

```
WHERE ProductDetails.pegadaEcologica = 'Low' --searches for a 'low ecological footprint' product only
```

or

```
WHERE ProductDetails.nome = 'Black Show' -- Searches for black shoes in the name of the product
```

or

```
WHERE ProductDetails.codigo = 35 -- Searches for the item with the ID of 35
```

....

Comment: Thank you, this worked, and now I understand it better. Thank you ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to test it out, so you may get some syntax errors.  Give this a try and see if it works:

```
-- Get e-mail of consumer who bought products which include all elements
SELECT cdr.email
FROM compra cmp -- Get all purchases
INNER JOIN consumidor cdr ON cmp.consumidor = cdr.numero -- Get consumer info
WHERE (cmp.produto, cmp.prodMarca) IN ( -- Only look at purchases which included products that included all elements
    SELECT pto.codigo, pto.marca
    FROM produto pto -- Get all products
    INNER JOIN composto cpt ON pto.codigo = cpt.produto AND cpt.prodMarca = pto.marca -- Get all elements defined for each product
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elemento) -- Only return products that have all elements
    GROUP BY pto.codigo, pto.marca
);
```

Also, you may want to keep the same or similar column names FOR PK/FK references.  This makes it easier to read and understand your SQL/schema.  Let me know if it works.